# SSIS: How to set a Expression value from SQL Executable Task

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a SQL Executable task in which I am checking the count(*) of records in a particular table.

```
select count(*) as Is_Data from TABLE_NAME;
```

I need to get the Is_Data value out as an expression, so that based on the value the next execution start.

How to get the Is_Data value out from SQL Executable task

Thanksc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ResultSet to single row:

[image]

Configure a variable on the Result Set tab.  This variable can then be used in subsequent tasks:

[image]